# How do you create a database table using JSON data?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, json

Right now i have this JSON data

```
d={"db_table_name":"form_for_hub_trooper_in_store_feedback_form_20160829174321","Date of Audit":"","Name of Auditor":"","Store Location":"","Name of Staff":"","greet_score":"0"}
```

what i would like to do is to create a database table. The table name will be named after `db_table_name` while the column names will be from `Date of Audit`...and more.

Comment: MYSQL has no support for creating tables based on a JSON string. You need to use the language your coding in to json_decode your string in to either an array or object and build the SQL statement through a script/code. How come you want to create tables from a JSON string? surely just writing out the query  manually would be the safest and better option

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i have tried using `for-each` loop to get the keys(.key) and values(.value) from the JSON file. The problem is that if i do it this way, how am i supposed to create a database table? because i cant put the  `create` statement in the `for-each` statement because i still have other JSON data to add in. And i cant put it outside of the  `for-each` statement because how are you gonna retrieve those values out? not to say, its dynamic, meaning there could be 100 data in the JSON file.